# My facebook app is not showing in timeline manage section

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've created a simple facebook app for managing books I read, and I want this app to be visible in facebook timeline manage section. For instance I can see other apps in my timeline section like GoodReads and others. How it can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a feature a while ago, but Facebook has since removed it.

Some “legacy” apps that implemented this feature back when it was available are still able to use it; but new apps can not use it any more.